# Is the standard name for a space of linear maps from one vector space into another?

Tags: vector-spaces, dual-spaces

I know that linear maps from $V \rightarrow K$ create a space called dual.
What are the names for other spaces created by linear maps where $K$ is some subspace of $V$ where is $V \gt K$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The set of all linear maps T:V->W is a vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381942/the-set-of-all-linear-maps-tv-w-is-a-vector-space)

Comment: I know that it creates the vector space. The question was more about, what is the official name for sucha a space to search more information about this subject. For a special case it is called dual, do we have special names for other?
Thank you for you comment!
I have edited the question as it was misleading by the extra question in the end.

Comment: There is no name for this. Some denotes it as $L(X, Y)$.

Comment: OK, it is just as you wrote a space of linear maps from $X$ to $Y$. :) Thanks again!